# How do phase conjugating mirrors look like in render?

Tags: physics, rendering, raytracing, path-tracing

This question might not fit this community standards, so it might be closed in the future. I am interested in physics and I recently learned about phase conjugating mirrors. These are very special, because they bounce back light in the direction it came from, instead of obeying the usual Snell's law. It looks something like this:

[image]

This is very interesting, because it can be used to "undo" distortion like this:

[image]

My question is if somebody who has ever written a ray tracer/path tracer could implement this in an object. I'm very interested to see the result, but I have never written one of these myself and it would be overkill to write one for this result.

Image source: http://slehar.com/wwwRel/PhaseConjugate/PhaseConjugate.html

Comment: This does not seem to be a question about how to develop a new game or game mod, which is what we answer here. Can you edit your question to frame it in terms of a game or game mod you are making, or take it elsewhere, like to the Physics or Computer Graphics StackExchange sites? (Be sure to check their on-topic guidelines first)